# Consume external api into kentico

Tags: kentico

What is the best way to consume an external api's data?

Do I need to create a new web api project and set up routing?

In the past I use a web service data source and attached a repeater.  This won't work because I have an API instead of a web service.

Thanks much

Answer (score 1):

you can try this, this is how i've converted my JSON / XML apis (or anything really) into a Transformable object, just clone this tool and adjust to your needs

https://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/utilities/universal-api-viewer-(with-hierarchy-support)

A custom Data Source is what you would still want to do, as all a data source does really is return a Data Table, my tool there takes it another step by assigning it hierarchy structure and psuedo page types so the Repeater can treat them like items on the content tree.

---

After reading you can now connect externally do the database, you can use Kentico's ConnnectionHelper to connect to the external database via the Connection String, then query it.

If you have access to the external database, then you can use Kentico's ConnectionHelper class to pass in the external database connection string and run queries against it if you wish.

```
GeneralConnection ConnectionObj = ConnectionHelper.GetConnection("GetConnectionStringFromWeb.ConfigHere");
        ConnectionObj.Open();
        DataSet Results = ConnectionObj.ExecuteQuery(new QueryParameters("select * from SomeTable", null, QueryTypeEnum.SQLQuery));
```

Comment: Thank you, we decided to not use the API because we have access to the database.  Now trying to figure out how to call the external db and push the data into a custom table.